# Make div size as per contents and horizontally center inside it's parent

Tags: css, centering, alignment

I have a div message which basically has a text and a link. I want its size to be changing based on the string inside it. Also I want this message div to be centered inside its container.

I have been playing with it for a while without much luck. Here is the link to JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pDYJ8/

Also I don't know how make that text and link appear one after other ( not on the new line )

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="message">
    <p>do you want to </p> 
    <a href="somewhere" target="_blank">
        buy this product
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    background: #666;
    top:25%;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #e47911;
}
.message {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: #ddd;


    width:100px;   
}
```

**Tried display inline block to fit its content but then it wouldn't center it inside its parent.**

**Keeping width 100px for now just to mock my requirements**

Comment: There is not enough space for `p` and `a` elements to fit inline http://jsfiddle.net/pDYJ8/2/

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/pDYJ8/1/

Comment: ignore width:100px ( you can remove it ) I have kept it 100px just to mock my requirements ( to have it centered ). Updated my question to specify that.

Comment: @michalzuber: works great except it does not auto fit the content ( it is 200px by default ) I want width to change based on it's content.

Comment: Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/kEQZn/

Comment: @stackErr Yes except div 'message' should not be taking up entire width. It's width should only be of the size of it's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just Tweak Some CSS

[**See the demo fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pDYJ8/8/)

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    background: #666;
    top:25%;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #e47911;
    text-align: center; /*added*/
}
.container .message {
    display: inline-block; /*added*/
    text-align: left; /*added*/
    background: #ddd;
}

.message p { /*added*/
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Explanation**

The `text-align` center causes the now `inline-block` display of `.message` to center, which is then reset to have its own `text-align` back at left (this is not necessary). To get the `a` on the same line, the `p` also needs to be some type of inline display, here I chose `inline-block` as well..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over complicating things. All you need is a `text-align: center`on the container and a `display: inline-block` on the message:

```css
.container {
    background: #666;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #e47911;
    text-align: center;
}
.container .message {
    background: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/pDYJ8/9/

The inline block makes the div act as a word inside text, and the text-align center makes the 'word' align to the center...

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/pDYJ8/10/

Changes made to above link

```css
.container .message {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:auto;   
}
span{
    background: #ddd;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: This looks good but you have specified with 200px. My problem is that content can change and I want width of message div to just take up the same space as of it's contents ( something like display inline )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified approach to a couple of the answers given.  It reduces the amount of HTML and CSS needed.

**CSS**

```css
 .container {
      color: #e47911;
      text-align: center;
 }
 .message {
      display: inline;  
      background: #DDDDDD;
 }
```

**HTML**

```html
 <div class="container">
      <p class="message">
           Do you want to <a href="somewhere" target="_blank">buy this product</a>?
      </p>
 </div>
```

I would definitely put your anchor tag, `<a>` inside the paragraph tag, `<p>`.

You could even remove `display: inline;` from `.message` if you made it a `<span>` rather than a `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it with `display: table;` and `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  do you want to <a href="somewhere" target="_blank">buy this product</a>
</div>
```